Error loading Pytorch model checkpoint: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'
I'm trying to load the weights of a Pytorch model but getting this error: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x1f'.
Here is the weights loading code:
import os
import torch
import numpy as np
# from data_loader import VideoDataset
import timm

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print('Device being used:', device)

mname = os.path.join('./CDF2_0.pth')
checkpoints = torch.load(mname, map_location=device)
print("Checkpoint loaded successfully.")
model = timm.create_model('legacy_xception', pretrained=True, num_classes=2).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoints['state_dict'])
model.eval()


I have tried with different Pytorch versions. I have tried to inspect the weights by changing the extension to .zip and opening with archive manager but can't fix the issue. Here is a public link to the weights .pth file, I'm trying to load. Any help is highly appreciated as I have around 40 trained models that took around one month for training!

The error is typical when trying to open a gzip file as if it was a pickle or pytorch file, because gzips start with a 1f byte. But this is not a valid gzip: it looks like a corrupted pytorch file.
Indeed, looking at hexdump -C file.pt  | head (shown below), most of it looks like a pytorch file (which should be a ZIP archive, not gzip, containing a python pickle file named data.pkl). But the first few bytes are wrong: instead of starting like a ZIP file as it should (bytes 50 4B or ASCII PK), it starts like a gzip file (1f 8b 08 08). In fact it's exactly as if the first 31 bytes were replaced with a valid, empty gzip file (with a timestamp ff 35 29 67 pointing to November 4, 2024 9:00:47 PM GMT).
Your file:
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 ff 35 29 67  02 ff 43 44 46 32 5f 30  |.....5)g..CDF2_0|
00000010  2e 70 74 68 00 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44  |.pth...........D|
00000020  46 32 5f 30 2f 64 61 74  61 2e 70 6b 6c 46 42 0f  |F2_0/data.pklFB.|
00000030  00 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  |.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ|
00000040  80 02 7d 71 00 28 58 08  00 00 00 62 65 73 74 5f  |..}q.(X....best_|
00000050  61 63 63 71 01 63 6e 75  6d 70 79 2e 63 6f 72 65  |accq.cnumpy.core|
...

(inspecting the pickle data we can see a dictionary {"best_acc": ..., "state_dict": ...}) with the typical contents of a checkpoint of a pytorch model).
A valid zipped pickle produced by torch.save({"best_acc": np.array([1]), "state_dict": ...}, "CDF2_0.pth"):
00000000  50 4b 03 04 00 00 08 08  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PK..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0f 00 13 00 43 44  |..............CD|
00000020  46 32 5f 30 2f 64 61 74  61 2e 70 6b 6c 46 42 0f  |F2_0/data.pklFB.|
00000030  00 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  |.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ|
00000040  80 02 7d 71 00 28 58 08  00 00 00 62 65 73 74 5f  |..}q.(X....best_|
00000050  61 63 63 71 01 63 6e 75  6d 70 79 2e 63 6f 72 65  |accq.cnumpy.core|
...

A gzip containing an empty file with the same name and timestamp (with gzip --best) has 31 bytes, the same as your file's prefix (except for the two 'Operating System' bytes):
00000000  1f 8b 08 08 ff 35 29 67  02 03 43 44 46 32 5f 30  |.....5)g..CDF2_0|
00000010  2e 70 74 68 00 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00     |.pth...........|

Edit:
Here's a script that might fix such files in general:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copy2
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

import numpy as np
import torch

CHUNK_SIZE = 4

def main(orig_path: Path) -> None:
    fixed_path = orig_path.with_suffix(".fixed.pth")
    copy2(orig_path, fixed_path)

    with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        temp_path = Path(temp_dir) / orig_path.name
        torch.save({"best_acc": np.array([1]), "state_dict": {}}, temp_path)

        with open(temp_path, "rb") as f_temp:
            with open(fixed_path, "rb+") as f_fixed:
                while True:
                    content = f_fixed.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
                    replacement = f_temp.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
                    if content == replacement:
                        break
                    print(f"Replacing {content!r} with {replacement!r}")
                    f_fixed.seek(-CHUNK_SIZE, os.SEEK_CUR)
                    f_fixed.write(replacement)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert len(sys.argv) == 2, "Expected exactly one argument (the path to the broken .pth file)."
    main(Path(sys.argv[1]))


By the way, always use torch.load() with weights_only=True unless you're absolutely sure you trust the source. See the warning in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html

Excellent debugging and analysis. There’s actually a decent chance that the file is recoverable by restoring a valid ZIP file entry header. Of course, at this point it would probably be better to try and get a pristine copy of the file from its source, if at all possible.

Indeed, the file can be fixed with echo "504b0304000008080000000000000000000000000000000000000f00130043" | xxd -p -r | cat - <(tail -c +32 CDF2_0.pth) > fixed.pth and opened (in a podman or docker container for safety) like podman run --rm -it  -v $PWD:/try:ro,z  pytorch/pytorch  python -c 'import torch; o = torch.load("/try/fixed.pth", map_location="cpu"); print(o.keys())'

Thanks so much for detailed answer and comments! I will give it a try and mark the answer as accepted after it works.

@DevLoverUmar Any problems with the fix? It assumes Linux (bash). If you just need it for that one file, I've uploaded the result here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i3jeCAeeUI_Gd3n409X2bocppHp_n-BF/view?usp=sharing I can't guarantee it's safe to load though, it will execute arbitrary python code from wherever you took the original file.

Bravo! Checkpoint is loading successfully! Let me give it a try by loading the checkpoint and evaluating the weights! Can you please update the answer to make it easier to debug my remaining files. Thanks

@MarcinWrochna Thanks so much! this command is working in terminal to fix the corrupted header in model weights! I'm trying to create a python script but getting some mismatch.

Here is the hexdump of python script model fix. hexdump -C ./fixed_models/CDF2_0.pth  | head 00000000  50 4b 03 04 00 00 08 08  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PK..............| 00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 00  13 00 43 1f 8b 08 08 ff  |..........C.....| 00000020  35 29 67 02 ff 43 44 46  32 5f 30 2e 70 74 68 00  |5)g..CDF2_0.pth.| 00000030  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 44 46 32 5f 30 2f  |..........DF2_0/| 00000040  64 61 74 61 2e 70 6b 6c  46 42 0f 00 5a 5a 5a 5a  |data.pklFB..ZZZZ| 00000050  5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a 5a  5a 5a 5a 80 02 7d ...

@DevLoverUmar I edited the answer to add a python script that might help. In your hexdump, it looks like you concatenated the good 31 bytes + your whole CDF2_0.pth file, without removing the bad first 31 bytes of the latter.
